# Find Elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find a div with class "kinder" that have a element "a". I need to get and alert the href attribute from a.

**UPDATED EXEMPLE:** For example. If I had:

```
<div class="controls-wrapper">
    <div class="title" role="contentinfo">
        <header>  
            <div class="kinder" aria-hidden="true"> 
                <a tabindex="-1" href="https://google.com" target="_blank"> 
                    <img src="https://imageUrl/120x120.jpg" alt="" width="60" height="60"> 
                </a> 
            </div>
```

I need to alert "http://google.com"

I have tried the following code:

```
var aUserVideo = document.getElementsByClassName('kinder')

aUserVideoHref = aUserVideo.attribute("a");
aUserVideoHref = aUserVideoHref.attribute("href");

alert(aUserVideoHref);
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problems:**

1. The javascript method **[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** return array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names, so you've to target the object you want to use by index (example to get the first use `aUserVideo[0]`).
2. If you want to get an attribute you should use `getAttribute()` instead of `attribute`.

**Suggested Solution :**

You could simply get the href using `querySelector` with `.href` like :

```
document.querySelector(".kinder a").href
```

Hope this helps.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  console.log(document.querySelector(".kinder a").href);
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="kinder" aria-hidden="true"> <a tabindex="-1" href="http://google.com" target="_blank"> <img src="https://imageUrl/120x120.jpg" alt="" width="60" height="60"> </a> </div>
```

Comment: This wont work if the div doesnt have an anchor tag. The question is a little ambiguous about whether or not  that is possible.

Comment: That true, and the OP says _I need to find a div with class "kinder" that have a element "a"_ so we've to get just the anchors inside `.kinder`.

Comment: I'm getting undefined

Comment: Do you've the same HTML structure as the posted in the OP?

Comment: Does querySelector return an array? If so href would be undefined based on this answer.

Comment: You should seach before @Marie .. and the answer is no `querySelector ` doesn't return an array.

Comment: @sdadsad are you wrapping your script by the load method? check my update please.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki `console.log($('.kinder a'));` returns **Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → 54, selector: ".kinder a" }** but `console.log($('.kinder a').attr('href'));` reutrns undefined

Comment: Looks like your script can't find the elment you show us in the OP so it may executed before the present of the previous elements that why i suggest to use `ready` function of `DOMContentLoaded` as shown in my update.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki no...I have no idea why I cant get anchor...I can get others elements, but this anchor dont...

Comment: So strange, try to provide a fiddle with full code that reproduce the issue.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki can we talk in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131710/discussion-between-sdadsad-and-zakaria-acharki).

Answer (score 2):

You have your post tagged with jQuery. Here's the jQuery way to do it:

```
alert( $('.kinder a').prop('href') );
```

Or vanilla JavaScript:

```
alert ( document.querySelectorAll('.kinder a')[0].href );
```

Comment: I got undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with Jquery using the `attr` function like this:

**Jquery:**

```
alert($('.kinder a').attr('href'));
```

Regards!

Comment: Dupe of earlier answer.

Comment: I'm getting 'undefined'

Comment: You are using jquery or not?